# Transfer a byte[] via TCP Socket in android

Tags: java, android

I need to transfer a byte[] via TCP Socket in android -client side.
i tried to use the following code :

```
public static int readBytes(byte[] myByteArray) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

    int len = dis.readInt(); //<-here i get the error

    byte[] data = new byte[len];
    if (len > 0) {
        dis.readFully(data,0,len);
    }
    myByteArray=data;
    return data.length;
}
```

but I get the following error:

> 12-23 17:30:49.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11717):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: array size too large(Heap Size=5699KB,
>   Allocated=3403KB, Bitmap Size=78KB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably get the `OutOfMemoryError` on the line below. (The line that allocates new memory using `new`.)

Print `len` before doing the allocation and you'll probably see that it's a **huge number** (a lot larger than what you expect).

```
Log.d("YOU_TAG", "len = " + len);
```

Presumably you don't *send* the size of the byte array on the sending side. (Or if you do, your reading / writing has come out of sync.)

Comment: you are right, i don't send on the server side the size of the byte array, but the entire byte array
i send the data with Socket.Send(byte[]) -the server side is written in c# (it is a desktop application) How can i modify my function to read out the entire byte[]?

Comment: You can't. You need to start by sending the length of the array.

Comment: i saw that in c# there is a Socket.Receive(byte[]) method, there is no similar method in java?

Comment: i found this article about sending byte array over socket:http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_21993021.html, but how can i  implement this for reading the byte []?

Comment: If you don't know how many bytes was sent, then there's no way to figure out how many bytes you should read... Do you understand that?

Answer (score 0):

you must read in a closed loop like this:

```
while(true){
int len = dis.readInt();
}
```

Comment: i think thats for the server side